# Rewrite URL not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site in a subfolder like this: `www.example.com/TEST`. I want to rewrite a URL for a specific page which is from `post_type = page`.

For example, I have a page like this: `www.example.com/TEST/albama-test`

And I need end result URL to be like: `www.example.com/TEST/albama-test/blog`

How do I achieve this?

I tried to use `add_rewrite_rule` but it's not working for me.

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^blog/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=1053', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Comment: did you re-save permalinks after creating the rule?

Comment: Yes David but its not working after re-saving

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
        add_rewrite_rule('albama-test/blog/?(/([^/]+))?/?','index.php?pagename=albama-test','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```